# how to filter results with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, api, model-view-controller, filter

i have JSONResults in Controller, and now i have all data from table in JSONResults, at html detail view page for clients i have javascript and take all data.
  How to take data from Json, where client name is eqal to klID(This is json string where is client name).

i tried with this but again take all data in view.

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
 $.data = (json[i].klID = "@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.klient)");
                    var dateString = json[i].datum.substr(6);
                    var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
                    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
                    var day = currentTime.getDate();
                    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
                    var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

                    tr = $('<tr/>');
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].pID + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td id='date'>" + date + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].description + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].popust + "</td>");
                    $('table').append(tr);
```

Please Help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code is not relate to your problem, I didn't see any filer here. if you want only display kIID == client just put  if condition like below

```
if(json[i].klID === 'What ever name'){
 var dateString = json[i].datum.substr(6);
                    var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
                    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
                    var day = currentTime.getDate();
                    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
                    var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

                    tr = $('<tr/>');
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].pID + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td id='date'>" + date + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].description + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].popust + "</td>");
                    $('table').append(tr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in ES6 you can do a true filter:

```
const myArray = ['a', 2, 'b', 3, 4];
const filtered = myArray.filter((entry) => (
  isNaN(parseInt(entry))
);
console.log(filtered); // output: ['a', 'b']
```